# Inline C# if statement before binding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application created by another user and I have never used the functionality he has added where he seems to be using C# inside the ASPX document to bind data from a table.

Here is the code where he seems to bind data:

```
<table class="device_edit_device_table">
    <tr>
        <th><%: Resources.UserEditUserControlDevicesSerialNumber %></th>
        <th><%: Resources.UserEditUserControlDevicesCountry %></th>
        <th><%: Resources.UserEditUserControlDevicesSoftwareVersion %></th>
        <th><%: Resources.UserEditUserControlDevicesPlatform %></th>
        <th><%: Resources.UserEditUserControlDevicesCompany %></th>
        <th><%: Resources.UserEditUserControlDevicesPurchaseDate %></th>
        <th><%: Resources.UserEditUserControlDevicesPurchaseLocation %></th>
        <th><%: Resources.UserEditUserControlDevicesRegistrationDate %></th>
        <th><%: Resources.UserEditUserControlDevicesDeviceType %></th>
        <th><%: Resources.UserEditUserControlDevicesPreOwned %></th>
        <th>Lost</th>
        <th>Stolen</th>
        <th style="width:200px">Admin Comments</th>
        <th>Edit Device</th>
        <th>Edit Device Registration</th>
        <th>De-register Device</th>
    </tr>

  <tr>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.SerialNumber ?? string.Empty %></td>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.UnitCountry.Country ?? string.Empty%></td>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.UnitSoftwareVersion.Version ?? string.Empty%></td>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.UnitPlatform.Name ?? string.Empty%></td>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.UnitCompany.Name ?? string.Empty%></td>
      <td><%: Model.PurchaseDate.ToString() %></td>
      <td><%: Model.PurchaseLocation ?? string.Empty%></td>
      <td><%: Model.RegistrationDate.ToShortDateString()%></td>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.UnitBundle.Bundle %></td>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.IsSecondHand ? Resources.UserEditUserControlDevicesPreOwnedYes : Resources.UserEditUserControlDevicesPreOwnedNo %></td>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.Lost ?? false ? "Yes" : "No"%></td>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.Stolen ?? false ? "Yes" : "No"%></td>
      <td style="width:200px"><%: Model.Unit.Comments%></td>
      <td><%: Html.ActionLink("Edit Device", "Edit", "Unit", new { id = Model.SerialID, redirectTo = "DeviceDetailsPage" }, null)%></td>
      <td><%: Html.ActionLink("Edit Device Registraion", "Edit", "Registration", new { id = Model.RegistationID, redirectTo = "DeviceDetailsPage" }, null)%></td>
      <td><%: Html.ActionLink("De-register", "Deregister", "Device", new { id = Model.RegistationID }, null)%></td>

  </tr>
```

Now this page has `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Satmap.RouteShare.Web.Models.DeviceRegistration>"` but i can't seem to find the class `DeviceRegistration` which is why i think it points to a database table.

I have recently added column to the database 'Removed' and if this is true I dont want that row of data to be bound. Is there anyway that i can check for this Removed column in the `DeviceRegistration` and if its true dont load the data?

Comment: sounds like your first issue is finding that DeviceRegistration model? If you do a findall in your solution for `DeviceRegistration`, you don't find anything else? And if you already added a col to some "DeviceRegistration" table, have you tried simply trying to access it in your view?

Answer (score 1):

This is Razor syntax, from MVC 2 or below.You can add an if clause to it using Linq like:

```
<%: if(!Model.Removed) { %>
    <tr>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.SerialNumber ?? string.Empty %></td>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.UnitCountry.Country ?? string.Empty%></td>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.UnitSoftwareVersion.Version ?? string.Empty%></td>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.UnitPlatform.Name ?? string.Empty%></td>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.UnitCompany.Name ?? string.Empty%></td>
      <td><%: Model.PurchaseDate.ToString() %></td>
      <td><%: Model.PurchaseLocation ?? string.Empty%></td>
      <td><%: Model.RegistrationDate.ToShortDateString()%></td>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.UnitBundle.Bundle %></td>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.IsSecondHand ? Resources.UserEditUserControlDevicesPreOwnedYes : Resources.UserEditUserControlDevicesPreOwnedNo %></td>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.Lost ?? false ? "Yes" : "No"%></td>
      <td><%: Model.Unit.Stolen ?? false ? "Yes" : "No"%></td>
      <td style="width:200px"><%: Model.Unit.Comments%></td>
      <td><%: Html.ActionLink("Edit Device", "Edit", "Unit", new { id = Model.SerialID, redirectTo = "DeviceDetailsPage" }, null)%></td>
      <td><%: Html.ActionLink("Edit Device Registraion", "Edit", "Registration", new { id = Model.RegistationID, redirectTo = "DeviceDetailsPage" }, null)%></td>
      <td><%: Html.ActionLink("De-register", "Deregister", "Device", new { id = Model.RegistationID }, null)%></td>
  </tr>
<%: } %>
```

If you'd added a column to the Database then you'll need to update the Model to include that column "Removed" though. I'm guessing it's database-first entity framework so lookup how to update the edmx file from the Db.

For what it's worth, it's not good practice to have your views bound to your database models like this. You would usually have a view model to abstract the two layers from each other.

Comment: how do i write the foreach in the razor syntax?

Comment: Can you update your answer to include what's above the <tr> please?

Comment: check , Updated now

Comment: i am getting invalid expression term on the IF

Comment: You'll get that if the model hasn't been updated to include the field you've added to the DB, as described in the second part of my answer.